# JavaアプリケーションでBGMを流したい｡ (getResource() が null を返す)

Tags: java, classloader

Java アプリケーションで BGM を流したいと思い､次のクラスを作りました｡

```
import java.applet.Applet;

public class Sound {
    java.applet.AudioClip ac;
    public Sound() {
        // TODO 自動生成されたコンストラクター・スタブ
        ac = Applet.newAudioClip(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("res/BGMn.wav"));
    }

    public void loop(){
        ac.loop();
    }
    public void stop(){
        ac.stop();
    }
    public void play(){
        ac.play();
    }
}
```

しかし､ main スレッドで呼び出したところ､次のようなエラーが出てしまいました｡

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at sun.applet.AppletAudioClip.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.applet.Applet.newAudioClip(Unknown Source)
at boss.Sound.<init>(Sound.java:9)
at boss.Main.init(Main.java:68)
at boss.Main.main(Main.java:45)
```

`getResource()` のパスが間違っていると思われるのですが､いろいろ試してみてもできませんでした｡  パスには何を指定すれば良いのでしょうか｡

**ディレクトリ構造:**

```
Project
  src
    package
      Main.java
      Sound.java
  res
    BGMn.wav
```

**.classpath:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
```

Comment: `Main.class`などがどこに生成されているかや、クラスパスの設定を確認する必要がありそうです。

Comment: `Main.class`は`bin/Project`以下に生成されていました｡

Comment: クラスパスには以下の記述がありました｡
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<classpath>
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="src"/>
 <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
 <classpathentry kind="output" path="bin"/>
</classpath>
`

Comment: `bin/Project`以下に、`res`ディレクトリごとコピーしたら良いかもしれません。eclipseでの正しいクラスパスの設定方法はよく知らないのでパスです。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

リソースファイルがみつからないのは実行時にres以下のファイルがパスの通ったディレクトリへコピーされていないからだと思われます。

あなたのプロジェクトではbinディレクトリにビルド結果が出力されそこにパスが通った状態で実行されるようになっていると思います。（特に指定せずにプロジェクトを作成するとそうなります。）しかし、src以外のファイルは標準設定ではbinへコピーされないのでgetResourceが失敗する結果になります。

Project->Properties->Java Build PathのSourceタグでresディレクトリーを追加することでresディレクトリにおいたリソースファイルがbinへコピーされるようになります。どこにコピーされるかはProject->Clean...を実行してビルドしなおした状態でbinディレクトリの下を観察してみてください。

またいちいちresをソースディレクトリーとして設定しなくても、例えばMain.javaと同じ場所(src/package/.)へリソースファイルを置くと`Main.class.getResource("BGMn.wav")`でアクセスできるので簡単です。

Comment: ありがとう御座います｡  無事BGMを流すことが出来ました｡

Answer (score 2):

大雑把に説明しますと`.classpath`ファイルの通り、`kind="src"`で指定されている`src`ディレクトリ配下にあるファイルが、コンパイル後`kind="output"`で指定されている`bin`ディレクトリに格納されます。

**コンパイル後のディレクトリ構成(現状):**

```
Project
  bin
    package
      Main.class
      Sound.class
  res
    BGMn.wav
```

※`src`ディレクトリは省略

つまりこのままだとコンパイル後に`bin`ディレクトリに`BGMn.wav`が含まれませんし、実行時に`Sound`クラスからwavファイルを参照することもできません。

`res`ディレクトリを`src/package`配下に移動してください。
そうすれば`Sound`クラスから`"res/BGMn.wav"`でwavファイルを参照できます。

**ディレクトリ構成(修正後):**

```
Project
  src
    package
      Main.java
      Sound.java
      res
        BGMn.wav
  bin
    package
      Main.class
      Sound.class
      res
        BGMn.wav
```